# Find all nodes containing capital letter in specific property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, opencypher

I'm new to Neo4j. I want to fetch all nodes whose one of property for example `name` contains a capital character at any position. I saw the `CONTAINS` clause provided but was unable to use it with RegEx as Compiler does not accept `=~` after CONTAINS keyword in the query.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ '.*[A-Z]+.*'
RETURN n
```

Ideally, you will want to at least restrict the initial pattern (here: `(n)`) by a label (let's say: `Person`):

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name =~ '.*[A-Z]+.*'
RETURN n
```

... and create an index for that label and property to speed up the lookup:

```
CREATE INDEX person_name IF NOT EXISTS FOR (p:Person) ON (p.name)
```